# How to evaulate this integral using Newtons binomial theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, binomial-theorem

> Evaluate the following definite integral:
>   $$\int_0^{0.5}(3-5x)^{\frac{4}{3}} \ \mathrm dx$$

I'm working with this integral and I want to solve it using Newton's Binomial Theorem. Not sure how to go about that. Could use some tips/help

Comment: Actually your question tells nothing. What integral are you dealing with?

Comment: I included a picture of the integral

Comment: I suppose then that you want to approximate the result.

Comment: Why do you want to use the Newton binomial theorem? That seems overkill. Could you please provide us, where exactly, you get stuck?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes

Comment: @mickep my instructor asked us to but we've learned nothing about it and i can't really find anything helpful online. I have no idea how how to approach this using the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Normal method

Let $u=3-5x$. Then, $\mathrm du = -5 \ \mathrm dx$.

Also, $x=\dfrac{3-u}5$. Then, $\mathrm dx = -\dfrac15\ \mathrm du$.

When $x=0$, $u=3$; when $x=0.5$, $u=0.5$.

Then:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_0^{0.5}(3-5x)^{\frac{4}{3}} \ \mathrm dx
&=& \displaystyle \int_3^{0.5}u^{\frac{4}{3}} \left(-\dfrac15 \ \mathrm du\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac15 \int_{0.5}^3 u^{\frac{4}{3}} \ \mathrm du \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac15 \left(\dfrac{3u^{\frac73}}{7}\right)_{0.5}^3\\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac3{35} \left(9\sqrt[3]3-0.25\sqrt[3]{0.5}\right)\\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac3{280} \left(72\sqrt[3]3-\sqrt[3]{4}\right)\\
\end{array}$$

---

### Binomial theorem

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_0^{0.5}(3-5x)^{\frac{4}{3}} \ \mathrm dx
&=& \displaystyle 3\sqrt[3]3 \int_0^{0.5} \left(1-\dfrac53x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle 3\sqrt[3]3 \int_0^{0.5} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dbinom{4/3}{n} \left(-\dfrac53x\right)^n\right) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle 3\sqrt[3]3 \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^{0.5} \dbinom{4/3}{n} \left(-\dfrac53x\right)^n \ \mathrm dx\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle -\dfrac{9\sqrt[3]3}5 \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{n+1} \dbinom{4/3}{n} \left(-\dfrac56\right)^{n+1}\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle -\dfrac{9\sqrt[3]3}5 \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac37 \dbinom{7/3}{n+1} \left(-\dfrac56\right)^{n+1}\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle -\dfrac{27\sqrt[3]3}{35} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dbinom{7/3}n \left(-\dfrac56\right)^n\right) \\
&=& -\dfrac{27\sqrt[3]3}{35} \left[\left(1-\dfrac56\right)^{\frac73} - 1\right]\\
&=& -\dfrac{27\sqrt[3]3}{35} \left[\dfrac1{6^{\frac73}} - 1\right]\\
&=& \dfrac{3}{140\sqrt[3]2} \left[36\sqrt[3]6 - 1\right]\\
&=& \dfrac{3}{280} \left[72\sqrt[3]2 - \sqrt[3]4\right]\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do it by binomial theorem? I understand how to do the normal integration of it. I did some reading up on the binomial theorem but I don't understand how to to put this integral in that form

Comment: @sfr Why would you want to do it with the binomial theorem?

Comment: My instructor asked us to but we haven't learned anything about it at all and I wasn't able to find many good resources online.

Comment: I was wondering what would happen with the limits on the integral. Now I understand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sfr Really?? You didn't find any "good resources" online about this? Because there surely are several many thousands with "generalized binomial theorem" (142,000, more or less)...

Comment: Yes really. For someone who doesn't know anything about it, it's difficult to find a good simple example to follow by.

Answer (score 0):

To use the binomial theorem for fractional exponents, you should make one of the terms inside the parentheses be $1$, in which case the other has to be less than 1 in magnitude in order to guarantee that the series converges. In this case notice that $|5x| \leq 2.5<3$ on the domain of interest, so we write

$$(3-5x)^{4/3}=3^{4/3}(1-(5/3)x)^{4/3}.$$

Once you are in that form you just plug in the formula $(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {\alpha \choose n} x^n$ where ${\alpha \choose n}$ is defined to be $\frac{\alpha (\alpha-1) \cdots (\alpha-n+1)}{n!}$. You can then integrate term-by-term to get a series representation of the integral. Finally you can rearrange this series back into binomial theorem form in order to get a closed form solution.

This is *much* more difficult than just taking a substitution and using the power rule, but it does work in the end.